# How to create plist from xlsx

Tags: ios, cocoa, plist, xlsx

I have an xlsx with two column named "NAME" and "NICK_NAME". I want to create a plist file with "NAME" entries as dictionary keys and "NICK_NAME" entries as corresponding values. Inside the plist file there should be a dictionary which contains all the key-value(NAME-NICK_NAME)pairs. How can I create such a plist file from xlsx.

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to parse the .xlsx file
2. then organize data in the NSDictionary form
3. Write NSdictionary to plist file

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to export it as CSV, convert that into JSON (http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm) then you can parse the JSON easily or save it direct to plist as it should already be a dictionary...